# Generic pom.xml for building an executable jar: How can I specify dependency groupId/artifactId/version at runtime?

Tags: java, maven, properties

I have a situation where we work with Maven inside Eclipse and we end up with many artifacts containing code to deploy.  Works very well.

One of our target platforms invokes a plainly named executable jar in a very specific location, and after a bit of experimenting I have found that a suitable runnable jar can be created by having a *new* pom.xml depending solely on the artifact created from the Eclipse project, which then invokes first copy-dependencies to get the dependencies from the artifact and then creates an empty jar in the right location but with Main-Class and Class-Path set correctly in the manifest.

This works well for our test projects but now I want to generalize it, so I need to be able to provide the groupId/artifactId/version for the artifact to deploy at invocation time.

I have experimented with the properties-maven-plugin like

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
        <file>foobar.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

expecting

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${artifact.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>${artifact.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <version>${artifact.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

to be filled out correctly.  Unfortunately Maven complains:

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for ${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}:jar with value '${artifact.artifactId}' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 85, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}:jar with value '${artifact.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 84, column 16
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for ${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}:jar must be a valid version but is '${artifact.version}'. @ line 86, column 16
```

There will only be that single dependency.  How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. Use the maven-archetype-plugin to make a template that stamps out new projects each time.

Comment: I do not like the idea of pom.xml being new every time, but I like that the pom.xml is complete (instead of depending on properties not included).  I've made this work.  Note to others:  Do _not_ have periods in your template variables.